# Java: Adding numbers in linked lists giving strange results

Tags: java, linked-list

I have to write a program that stores up to 10 arbitrarily long numbers in an array of linkedLists and then adds them together, stores them in an 11th list and then outputs the results. I've written all the code, but I'm getting wonky results when I print out the results. Here's my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class LongNumbers {

   private List<Integer> [] theLists;

   public LongNumbers(){
   this.theLists = new LinkedList[11];
   for (int i=0; i<11; i++)
   this.theLists[i]= new LinkedList<>();
}

public void add(int location, int digit)
{
//add digit at head of LinkedList given by location
theLists[location].add(digit);
}
public int remove(int location)
{
//remove a digit from LinkedList given by location
    return theLists[location].remove(location);
}
public boolean isEmpty(int location)
{
//check for an empty LinkedList given by location
return theLists[location].isEmpty();
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

//local variables
String number;
boolean userWantsToQuit = false;
LongNumbers lists = new LongNumbers();
int currArrayLocation = 0;
int currDigit = 0;
int maxLength = 0;
int numsEntered = 0;
int finalDigit = 0;
int carryDigit = 0;
char[] digits;

//get data
do{
System.out.println("Enter a number, or enter -1 to escape.");
number = kb.nextLine();

if(number.equals("-1"))
    userWantsToQuit = true;
else {
    numsEntered++;
    if (number.length()> maxLength) 
        maxLength = number.length();
    digits = new char[number.length()]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++){
        digits[i] = number.charAt(i);
        currDigit = digits[i]-48;
        lists.add(currArrayLocation, currDigit);}
    } 
    currArrayLocation++;

} while (!userWantsToQuit && currArrayLocation < 9 );
//if the linkedLists are full
if (currArrayLocation == 9)
    System.out.println("The max amount of numbers have been entered.");

//to add numbers into final linked list
for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++){
    for (currArrayLocation = 0; currArrayLocation < numsEntered; currArrayLocation++){
       if (lists.theLists[currArrayLocation]== null){
            lists.remove(0);}
            //currDigit = 0;
       else{
            currDigit = lists.theLists[currArrayLocation].get(0);
        int tempDigit = currDigit;
        System.out.println("temp: " + tempDigit); //test line
        finalDigit += tempDigit;
        System.out.println(finalDigit); //test line
        }



    //add the proper digit to the last LinkedList and set carry digit
    finalDigit = finalDigit + carryDigit;
    carryDigit = finalDigit/10;
    //lists.add(10, finalDigit);
    //lists.remove(0); 
    //finalDigit = 0;       
} 
lists.add(10, finalDigit);
lists.remove(0);
finalDigit = 0;   
}
//print the sum
if (lists.theLists[10] != null){
        System.out.print("Sum: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < lists.theLists[10].size() ; i++){
        System.out.print(lists.theLists[10].get(i));
        }
    }
}//end main
}//end class
```

When I add together 100 and 200, I get 322. I believe my problem is in the lines following the comment //to add numbers into final linked list.

Any insight or ideas would be great, thank you in advance!

Comment: So the goal here is to just add up a bunch of really really big numbers using an array? Or is there a specific assignment that dictates your implementation?

Comment: It's an assignment that requires using an array of linked lists to add the numbers together @JonahHaney

Comment: Kind of a silly assignment considering java.math.BigInteger has a much smoother implementation of storing big numbers.

Comment: Jonah, I cannot thank you enough. This is the most thorough answer I've ever seen on this site, and I really appreciate you walking me through each step. My professor isn't particularly helpful and I feel like I truly understand what went wrong in each step now, and isn't that what every programmer should aim for? Thanks again, and sorry for the delay in response @JonahHaney

Comment: No problem man, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah there's actually a LOT of problems with this one.

I put your code through BlueJ's debugger and, after much painful debugging, I finally found the issue.  Pretty quickly I realized your line 81 should be:

```
currDigit = lists.theLists[currArrayLocation].get(i);
```

But if you do that, you get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, which confused me for a while, but I eventually discovered the problematic line 97:

```
lists.remove(0);
```

This led me to discover that your `public int remove(int location)` method was all wrong. The only thing it did was remove one digit in one of your numbers. I imagine that what you meant to do was something like this:

```
public void remove(int location)
{
    //remove a digit from LinkedList given by location
    for (int i=0; i<theLists[location].size(); i++){
        theLists[location].remove(i);
        theLists[location].add(i,0);
    }
}
```

Notice I changed the return type to `void` because theres no need to return anything here.

But then, why remove anything at the end of that loop anyway? After also deleting line 97 altogether the code works perfectly fine with output as you would expect:

```
Enter a number, or enter -1 to escape.
100
Enter a number, or enter -1 to escape.
200
Enter a number, or enter -1 to escape.
300
Enter a number, or enter -1 to escape.
-1
temp: 1
1
temp: 2
3
temp: 3
6
temp: 0
0
temp: 0
0
temp: 0
0
temp: 0
0
temp: 0
0
temp: 0
0
Sum: 600
```

But then, as per usual, this caused yet another problem. When adding together numbers with different lengths, we get another `IndexOutOfBoundsException` on line 81 (The line we fixed earlier).  Turns out this is caused by your top loop which assumes that every number entered is of the same length. To combat this, I wrote a method to enter leading zeroes at the beginning of all your numbers like this:

```
public static void bufferWithLeadingZeroes(List<Integer>[] theLists, int maxLength){
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
        int howManyToAdd = maxLength - theLists[i].size();
        for (int j=0; j<howManyToAdd; j++){
            theLists[i].add(0,0);
        }
    }
    theLists[10].add(0,0);
}
```

Then added in the method call: `bufferWithLeadingZeroes(lists.theLists,maxLength);` to line 73

After playing with that I discovered that the way you handle carrying digits is just all wrong, so I wrote a loop that would take care of that by iterating through the digits of the final entry in `lists` like this and added it to line 90:

```
if (finalDigit > 9){
    i++;
    int newDigit = lists.theLists[10].get(i-1) + (finalDigit/10);
    lists.theLists[10].remove(i-1);
    lists.theLists[10].add(i-1,newDigit);
    finalDigit %= 10;
    for (int j=(i-1); j>=0; j--){
        if (lists.theLists[10].get(j) > 9){
            if (j == 0){
                lists.theLists[10].add(j,0);
                j++;
                i++;
            }
            newDigit = lists.theLists[10].get(j-1) + 1;
            lists.theLists[10].remove(j-1);
            lists.theLists[10].add(j-1,newDigit);
            newDigit = lists.theLists[10].get(j) % 10;
            lists.theLists[10].remove(j);
            lists.theLists[10].add(j,newDigit);
        }
    }
    i--;
}
```

So now, finally, the sucker works. Here is the (abridged) output:

```
Enter a number, or enter -1 to escape.
734924
Enter a number, or enter -1 to escape.
3749223749
Enter a number, or enter -1 to escape.
423
Enter a number, or enter -1 to escape.
6432842
Enter a number, or enter -1 to escape.
3294492423442424
Enter a number, or enter -1 to escape.
-1
temp: 0
0
temp: 0
0
temp: 0
0
temp: 0
0
temp: 3
3
temp: 0

...

temp: 2
18
temp: 4
22
Sum: 03294496179834362
```

You'll notice that Sum is printed with a leading zero. You may want to alter your final loop that prints the numbers so that it will trim those.

---

So finally, here is our fully working code:

```
    import java.util.*;

public class LongNumbers {

    private List<Integer> [] theLists;

    public LongNumbers(){
        this.theLists = new LinkedList[11];
        for (int i=0; i<11; i++)
            this.theLists[i]= new LinkedList<>();
    }

    public void add(int location, int digit)
    {
        //add digit at head of LinkedList given by location
        theLists[location].add(digit);
    }

    public void remove(int location)
    {
        //remove a digit from LinkedList given by location
        for (int i=0; i<theLists[location].size(); i++){
            theLists[location].remove(i);
            theLists[location].add(i,0);
        }
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(int location)
    {
        //check for an empty LinkedList given by location
        return theLists[location].isEmpty();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        //local variables
        String number;
        boolean userWantsToQuit = false;
        LongNumbers lists = new LongNumbers();
        int currArrayLocation = 0;
        int currDigit = 0;
        int maxLength = 0;
        int numsEntered = 0;
        int finalDigit = 0;
        int carryDigit = 0;
        char[] digits;

        //get data
        do{
            System.out.println("Enter a number, or enter -1 to escape.");
            number = kb.nextLine();

            if(number.equals("-1"))
                userWantsToQuit = true;
            else {
                numsEntered++;
                if (number.length()> maxLength) 
                    maxLength = number.length();
                digits = new char[number.length()]; 
                for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++){
                    digits[i] = number.charAt(i);
                    currDigit = digits[i]-48;
                    lists.add(currArrayLocation, currDigit);}
            } 
            currArrayLocation++;

        } while (!userWantsToQuit && currArrayLocation < 9 );
        //if the linkedLists are full
        if (currArrayLocation == 9)
            System.out.println("The max amount of numbers have been entered.");
        bufferWithLeadingZeroes(lists.theLists,maxLength);
        //to add numbers into final linked list
        for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++){
            for (currArrayLocation = 0; currArrayLocation < numsEntered; currArrayLocation++){
                if (lists.theLists[currArrayLocation]== null){
                    lists.remove(0);}
                //currDigit = 0;
                else{
                    currDigit = lists.theLists[currArrayLocation].get(i);
                    int tempDigit = currDigit;
                    System.out.println("temp: " + tempDigit); //test line
                    finalDigit += tempDigit;
                    System.out.println(finalDigit); //test line
                }
            }
            if (finalDigit > 9){
                i++;
                int newDigit = lists.theLists[10].get(i-1) + (finalDigit/10);
                lists.theLists[10].remove(i-1);
                lists.theLists[10].add(i-1,newDigit);
                finalDigit %= 10;
                for (int j=(i-1); j>=0; j--){
                    if (lists.theLists[10].get(j) > 9){
                        if (j == 0){
                            lists.theLists[10].add(j,0);
                            j++;
                            i++;
                        }
                        newDigit = lists.theLists[10].get(j-1) + 1;
                        lists.theLists[10].remove(j-1);
                        lists.theLists[10].add(j-1,newDigit);
                        newDigit = lists.theLists[10].get(j) % 10;
                        lists.theLists[10].remove(j);
                        lists.theLists[10].add(j,newDigit);
                    }
                }
                i--;
            }
            lists.add(10, finalDigit);
            finalDigit = 0;
        }
        //print the sum
        if (lists.theLists[10] != null){
            System.out.print("Sum: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < lists.theLists[10].size() ; i++){
                System.out.print(lists.theLists[10].get(i));
            }
        }
    }//end main

    public static void bufferWithLeadingZeroes(List<Integer>[] theLists, int maxLength){
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
            int howManyToAdd = maxLength - theLists[i].size();
            for (int j=0; j<howManyToAdd; j++){
                theLists[i].add(0,0);
            }
        }
        theLists[10].add(0,0);
    }

}//end class
```